# Camelcase Component name Not working in Yii + Ubuntu Server

Tags: yii, yii-components

My component name is AdminGeneralComponent.php. But when i deployed the code in my Ubuntu server, this component stopped working and even not throwing any error at all.

Kindly suggest me how can i traced the problem and resolve it.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you post your config or a snippet of code where you use this component? Are you sure that the name is "AdminGeneralComponent.php" on the server?

Comment: Yes I am sure that component name is AdminGeneralComponent.php. Do you think this is a problem due to Ubuntu Server of so. And if yes then how can we deal with this issue. Thanks a lot for your reply